# How to stop git repositories from getting too big

Tags: git, bitbucket

After some weeks of commits, the .git file of my Matlab code repository reaches 1-1.5 GB of size. How can I keep the size of the git registry under control?

What I already do, as best practices, is:

1. avoid cluttering the repository with the huge amount of files that Matlab writes during my simulations, and that is done by updating the .gitignore file to avoid committing/pushing them
2. avoid including binary or office files that require huge commits in terms of number of lines edited
3. periodically using commands like

   ```
   git reflog expire --all --expire=now
   git gc --prune=now --aggressive
   ```

   to clean the registry

What I think is happening is that every time matlab simulates something and writes a lot of text files or .mat variables, git is keeping track of all the changes. Give it a week and the repo is over 1.5 GB.

Should I just keep on the repository the actual "code" and avoid saving any variable?

Comment: You're pretty much answering your own question: don't track generated files; only track source files.

Comment: what are the typical size of your matlab files? Actually git is designed for text files, putting binary data in it usually lead to this situation especially when files are big

Comment: are images (picture) files generated and tracked, too? git is known to be not really for image data (because of these occuring memory problems). If yes, exclude them too. And of course like my predecessors said: exclude binary files.

Comment: Here's a suggested .gitignore for matlab: http://gitignore.io/api/matlab Can you investigate yourself and work out what these large files are? e.g.  what files do you have on disk? If you look at the commit diffs (e.g. using gitk) can you see large files with lots of changes that you don't need?

Comment: Yes, I am actually trying to track only source files, but also .mat variables seem to create the problem and it is quite complicated to store them in a separate folder every time I save them! As far as pictures, no I don't push them. The gitignore helps a lot, I will investigate, thanks!

Comment: Ah, another question: is there a way for git to warn you if you are trying to commit a file with a huge amount of line changes? So I can look into it before committing!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can seperate data and code, 
with a file tree like:

\project

\project/code/matlab_files.m

\project/code/.git

\project/data/matlab_data_files

This way you are not pushing data to github. Before pushing make sure to clean the variables in matlab. This can be done by closing Matlab or with the "clear all" command. 
Want to keep data? write it to the /project/data folder.

Comment: Creating the repository inside a subfolder helps, yes, I will try to do it, but it's quite close to what I am already trying to do. My problem lies in finding which files are increasing the size of the repository and if there is a way other than creating a new one to solve the issue that I have now!

Comment: Just following up on this, I solved the problem long ago by adding a .gitignore for the folders, and by starting to push only by doing "git add *.m" for scripts in Matlab.

Answer (score 0):

```
find .git -name pack-*.idx -exec git verify-pack -v {} +
```

will list the contents of all packs and give the actual size each part takes in the pack files.  To associate those with names, most efficient overall is probably a join,

```
join <(find .git -name pack-*.idx -exec git verify-pack -v {} + | sort) \
     <(git rev-list --all --objects | sort) \
| sort -nk4,4
```

the field after the object type (`tree`, `blob`, `commit`, you're after the blobs) is the full size of the result in your worktree, the one after that, the fourth field, is the size its delta takes in the pack.  Change the order and it'll be easy to sort by file,   here's one to show just the files and the relevant bits of data, by file:

```
join <(git rev-list --all --objects | sort ) \
     <( find .git -name pack-*.idx -exec git verify-pack -v {} + \
        | awk '$2=="blob" { print $1,$3,$4 } ' \
        | sort) \
| sort -k2 -nk4
```

Comment: Yep, that is also working, thanks for the full answer!